# ORA-00905: Missing keyword in CASE expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error "ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 76"

While trying to run the following query.

```
WITH t as (    
SELECT tot.student_id,
tot.first_name,
tot.last_name,
tot.track_date,
MAX(track_date) over (partition by tot.student_id) as max_track_date
from student tot
inner join student_backup toov
on tot.student_id = toov.student_id
AND CASE WHEN tot.track_date IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE tot.track_date between    
toov.start_dt AND toov.start_dt + toov.duration/60/40 END 
where toov.course_id=163121)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @rawdog: AND can also be in the ON condition of a join (similar to WHERE).

Answer (score 3):

```
...
AND CASE WHEN tot.track_date IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE tot.track_date between 
toov.start_dt AND toov.start_dt + toov.duration/60/40 END
```

What is that supposed to do? You have a `CASE` expression, `WHEN... THEN...` and you get to the `ELSE` clause. Right after `ELSE` you have a column name and then the keyword `BETWEEN`. That makes no sense. `BETWEEN` is a logical operator, what is it doing there?

On further reading: it seems **you misplaced the keyword `END`**. It belongs **before** the keyword `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @MohsinALvi - I already answered: move the word END from where it is now to right before the word BETWEEN. I don't know if the query will be correct (you didn't tell us what the requirement is, to begin with); but it will resolve the syntax error you reported in your post.

Comment: You are right. I posted with wrong condition. Thanks for the help anyway :)